# Making a default program for php file extentions

Tags: php, windows-7

I am constantly getting the message box asking me what program to open my .php file extensions with and I did some reason to find out how to make a default program for the file type with windows 7 computers however when I found the list of file extensions I could change I was not able to find .php. Any suggestions on what to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well not sure if I should comment, or answer. But in all..

Its a windows file type assoication. Follow the directions here
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/change-which-programs-windows-uses-by-default

Its for Vista but similar rules apply. But on that note, I should respectfully mention though this question may fit in somewhere on stackexchange and its network, it doesn't fit here as this isn't a matter of scripting error and trying to assess the issue as its more of an OS problem, and likely the fact that you have one to many IDE's and or uninstalled one recently that didn't clean up after itself to well.

Answer (score 1):

Double click on a .php file, select "select a program from the list of installed programs," click OK, select the appropriate program (you may have to click Browse to find it), leave "always use the selected program to open this kind of file" checked, click OK.